# Fragments and Master-Detail Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android Development and I am a little bit confused of what is the difference between Fragments and Master-Detail Android. Are they complete different things? Are they related at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Master/Detail flow is a pattern that uses fragments alongside activities to display not only a list of object but their details as well. From the Android Studio Template:

> Creates a new master/detail flow, allowing users to view a collection of objects as well as details for each object. This flow is presented using two columns on tablet-size screens and one column on handsets and smaller screens. This template creates two activities, a master fragment, and a detail fragment.

What that means is that on a phone there will be an `ItemListFragment` associated with an `ItemListActivity` and an `ItemDetailFragment` associated with an `ItemDetailActivity`. So when you click on an item in the `ItemListFragment` it opens that items details in a new screen via the `ItemDetailFragment`. However when in tablet mode, there will only be `ItemListFragment` and `ItemDetailFragment` attached to an `ItemListActivity`. This allows for you to display both item list and item detail on larger screens like so:

[image: Master/Detail Flow]

Answer (score 0):

`Fragments` are used to implement the master-detail flow in Android.